# Why relaodData call the viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am maintaining an app developed by someone else and I got a strange behaviour when debugging it. when allocating a view controller object from another class, it will call `viewDidLoad`, in `viewDidLoad`, I make call to another method in which I fill in an array:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      [super viewDidLoad];
      [self fillArray];
}

-(void)fillArray{
    arrayProduct = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   //fill in the array from server
   [self.objTableView reloadData];//refresh the table view 
}
```

The strange behaviour is, once `[self.objTableView reloadData];` statement is executed, the `viewDidLoad` gets called again. Why is this happening? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Because you are reloading your table in other function. Once it's done with that function, it will again come to previous function to proceed with previous function.

Comment: Hi, I checked that, I am not reloading the table in other function.

Comment: By your question, you mean your table view is reloaded twice???? or your breakpoint comes twice to function `- (void)viewDidLoad`????

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is called twice, not `reloadData`!

Comment: u need to go through concept of calling functions one more time.

Comment: Have you done a search of the code for viewDidLoad? It either has to be called twice, or your controller is being alloc init'd twice for this to happen.

Comment: You should post the full code for fillArray

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by using flag.

Declare on `BOOL` variable and make it true before call the `reloadData` method. and in `viewDidLoad` check if variable is true then don't init your array.

Comment: Really this should be a last resort. It's not normal to have `viewDidLoad` called twice.

Comment: And then what?, when your view gets unloaded to free up memory